# How to use Guzzle 6 to retrieve paged data from an endpoint?

Tags: asynchronous, guzzle, serviceclient

We need to be able to retrieve all pages of Groups data via the Discourse API (https://docs.discourse.org).  We're using Guzzle 6, and it would seem to be possible to use the promises system that is part of Guzzle's **ServiceClient** class to retrieve all pages asynchronously, but there's nothing in the docs to suggest exactly how that's done (https://github.com/guzzle/command/blob/master/README.md).  Here's (roughly) what we're doing now.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\Description;
use Webbj74\JSDL\Loader\ServiceDescriptionLoader;

/**
 * @return GuzzleClient|null
 */
public function getClient()
{
    $config = [
        'base_uri' => 'https://connect.mycompany.org',
        'api_key' => 'XYZ',
        'api_username'  => 'system',
    ];


    $client = new Client($config);

    $this->serviceDescription = $this->loadServiceDescription();

    if (! empty($this->serviceDescription)) {
        $this->client = new GuzzleClient($client, $this->serviceDescription);

        return $this->client;
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @return Description|null
 */
protected function loadServiceDescription()
{
    $loader = new ServiceDescriptionLoader();

    try {
        $serviceDescription = new Description($loader->load($path = self::SERVICE_JSON));

        return $serviceDescription;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
        Logger::log('Error: ' . $errorMessage, 'ERROR', true);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The service description includes this:

```
{
    "operations": {
    "Groups": {
        "extends": "discourse.base",
      "httpMethod": "GET",
      "uri": "/groups.json"
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit confused why you have to use Guzzle commands to make requests. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean, as opposed to using curl?  There are a lot of things in Guzzle that I'd have to hand code if not. I'm pretty committed to Guzzle at this point.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: No. I think you are using the wrong package for Guzzle. You are suppose to use 'GuzzleHttp\Client' for Client, not 'GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient' from here https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/ I am not too sure, but that's how you usually make requests.

Comment: Thanks—I'll give that a look.